# giving focus after slideDown - input changes its height

Tags: javascript, jquery, focus

in the example below click on `button` and `wrap` will toggle
problem - the first input changes its height and it makes an aditional slideDown of entire `wrap`
the reason is `$('#inpname').focus();` line - without it everything is ok
how to keep the focus and avoid this additional effect ?

**update**

I tried - without success:

```
$('button').on('click', async function(){
    await $('#wrap').slideToggle();
  $('#inpname').focus();
});
```

```js
$('button').on('click', function(){
    $('#wrap').slideToggle();
  $('#inpname').focus();
});
```

```css
.wrap{display:none;}

.inpname, .inpcontact{
    display:block;
    height:36px;
    width:90%;
    padding:0 20px;
    background:#eee;
    border-radius:25px;
    font-family:montserrat;
    font-size:1.6rem;
    font-weight:500;
    letter-spacing:1px;
    color:#333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>
<input type='text' class='inpname' id='inpname' placeholder='lorem'>
<br>
<input type='text' class='inpcontact' id='inpcontact'>
<br>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you can do is this:

```
$('#wrap').slideToggle(function() {
  $('#inpname').focus();
});
```

This will run your focus after the slideToggle is done.

**Demo**

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  $('#wrap').slideToggle(function() {
    $('#inpname').focus();
  });
});
```

```css
.wrap {
  display: none;
}

.inpname,
.inpcontact {
  display: block;
  height: 36px;
  width: 90%;
  padding: 0 20px;
  background: #eee;
  border-radius: 25px;
  font-family: montserrat;
  font-size: 1.6rem;
  font-weight: 500;
  letter-spacing: 1px;
  color: #333;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button>CLICK</button>
<br><br>
<div class='wrap' id='wrap'>
  <input type='text' class='inpname' id='inpname' placeholder='lorem'>
  <br>
  <input type='text' class='inpcontact' id='inpcontact'>
  <br>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks. Have you any idea why `async await` doesn't work here ?

Comment: @provance Can't tell without seeing where you added "async await"

Comment: see my update, pls

Comment: If you ran that code above with the await, i would guess you get an error in the code.

Comment: could you give me the solution with `async await`, pls ?